# How can I stop all power management stuff on my broken Ubuntu installation?

Tags: ubuntu, power-management

I have a fresh installation of Karmic Koala which keeps freezing very soon after login.  I had this problem before with the same machine and the previous time I believe I solved it by booting up in safe mode and disabling all power management software, and then rebooting.  However, I can't remember how I disabled the power management stuff.  I don't remember if it was APM or ACPI or what.

Can you tell me how I can disable all power management stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to do this recently, here is what I did.

> At the grub menu selection screen,
>   highlight the kernel command line and
>   press "e" to edit that line. Add
>   acpi=off to the end of the line, press
>   enter then b to boot your computer.
>
> The change you have just made is for
>   this session only. To make it
>   permanent (if it solves your issue),
>   edit /boot/grub/menu.lst to include
>   this option.

from http://ubuntu-utah.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=57019

In Karmic, I believe they've done away with menu.lst, but you just need to add ACPI=off to whatever they use for the grub config (/boot/grub/grub.cfg I think).

Good luck